# Visualizing Set Sizes with Geometric Figures in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I have multiple data sets and I want to visually show "how much bigger" one is compared to the other. Therefore, I am thinking about something like planet models for kids in children's books where the sun (a large circle) is drawn next to the earth (smaller circle) to show how the sizes compare.

Is there a simple way in python of how I can achieve this in a jupyter notebook? My inputs would just be an array of numbers e.g. [50, 100].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `matplotlib` to draw patches:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [50, 100]

radii = np.array([(A / pi) ** .5 for A in data])

radii = radii / radii.max()
radii.sort()
radii = radii[::-1]
# def get_circle(A):
#     c = Circle()

colors = ['m', 'c']
circles = [Circle((0, 0), r, color=color) for r, color in zip(radii, colors)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for c in circles:
    ax.add_artist(c)

plt.axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])
ax.set_aspect(aspect=1)
```

[image]